# How to deal with elasticsearch delay when doing unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, elasticsearch, delay

There're some delay in elasticsearch from requesting to index a document to the document become searchable. I want to know how to deal with this in a unit test, for example, first index a document, then check if it is really indexed. Now I simply use a Thread.sleep() call to delay some time(I'm using a plain junit class), say 2 second. Is this OK? Or there're better solutions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can refresh the indeces after writting to elasticsearch.

By doing,

```
$ curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/index1,index2/_refresh'
```

> The refresh API allows to explicitly refresh one or more index, making
>   all operations performed since the last refresh available for search.
>   The (near) real-time capabilities depend on the index engine used. For
>   example, the internal one requires refresh to be called, but by
>   default a refresh is scheduled periodically.

[See @Elasticsearch website](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html#indices-refresh)

using java api,

```
 client.admin().indices().prepareRefresh().execute().actionGet()
```

using the JavaScript client :

```
client.indices.refresh({index : 'myIndex'});
```

Comment: I've checked it with embedded ES node and JUnit tests (Spock) and it works :) Nice catch!